# Test BNB / WBNB for Development testing purpose

Tags: web3js, blockchain, binance-smart-chain, binance, wrapped-tokens

I am in need of 100 test BNB for testing purpose but with faucet its not possible to get that much is there any way to have that much test bnb.
OR is there any existing liquidity of test BNB / WBNB with any other token where that Test BNB / WBNB must have any value in usd.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to obtain 100 TBNB as the faucet only give small amounts. As for liquidities, you can check on PancakeSwap on testnet by connecting you wallet to the BNB Testnet if there is any.

The best way to test something in this case would be to use a local fork of the network, through hardhat or Truffle for exemple. It basically clones the blockchain at a specified block and allows you to interact with it locally. On top of that, it allows you to impersonate accounts which could hold the amounts of TBNB you need. Note that you can fork any blockchain, testnet. or mainnets.
You can then interact with it however you want, create you liquidity or whatever you needs may be.

Check this for hardhat doc: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks
Or for Truffle: https://trufflesuite.com/blog/sandbox-forking-with-truffle-teams/

Answer (score 0):

For test networks you can deploy one token yourself and call it BNB. Mint as many as token you want for yourself. Then use this your self deployed token as BNB.